# Highlight menu item on scroll does not work

Tags: javascript

The problem I have is the next one:
Only the last section of my code add the class, but the rest not.
Each section of my html has a unique class and the same class is also in the list tags

```
const activ = () => {
    const linkMenus = document.querySelectorAll('a')
    sections.forEach(clas => {
        const view = clas.getBoundingClientRect()
        if (view.top < 50 && view.top >= -800){
            clas.classList.add("active");
            linkMenus.forEach(lis => {
                if (clas.classList.contains("active") && 
lis.classList.contains(clas.id)){
                    lis.classList.add("active_nav");
                 }
                 else {
                 lis.classList.remove("active_nav"); 
                 }
            })
        }
        else{
        clas.classList.remove("active"); 
        }
    })
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', activ)
```

Comment: `.contains` is a Java method, do you mean to use [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)?

Comment: I think .includes is only used to search for words within a String

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this idea before, I will put my HTML, CSS and JS code, you can read it and use the JS code, maybe it will help you.

you can see the code on Codepen or use the snippet.

If you have any question, ask me.

Focus on this code in the JavaScript:

```
window.scrollY > sections[i].offsetTop && window.scrollY < sections[i].offsetTop + sections[i].offsetHeight
```

Snippet:

```js
var sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section"),
    li       = document.getElementsByClassName("li"),
    i;

window.onscroll = function () {
    
    for ( i = 0 ; i < sections.length ; i = i + 1 ) {
        
        if ( window.scrollY > sections[i].offsetTop && window.scrollY < sections[i].offsetTop + sections[i].offsetHeight ) {
            
            li[i].classList.add("red");
            sections[i].classList.add("red");
            
        } else {
            li[i].classList.remove("red");
            sections[i].classList.remove("red");
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

```css
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    height:2800px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.fixed
{
    position:fixed;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:#ccc;
    right:20px;
    top:50px;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.fixed ul 
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.fixed ul li
{
    line-height:40px;
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
section
{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    background:yellowgreen;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:4px solid;
    margin-top:25px;
    line-height:600px;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.red
{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
    <ul>
        <li class="li">one</li>
        <li class="li">two</li>
        <li class="li">three</li>
        <li class="li">four</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<section>one</section>
<section>two</section>
<section>three</section>
<section>four</section>
```